# Java MySQL update from another class

Tags: java, mysql, function

I am using Java along with this [sql library](https://github.com/Huskehhh/MySQL). I am trying to execute a Update function that I created using this library, from another class. Here is my code;

Main Class:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
  Player player = (Player)sender;
      if (command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("testvote")) {
            try {
                this.mysql.updatePlayer(player);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          return true;
      }
  return false;
  }
```

This should work fine, but the *this.mysql.updatePlayer(player);* will only work if I add a static to the code in my other class:

```
public void updatePlayer(Player p) throws SQLException{
    String pname = p.getDisplayName().toLowerCase();
    Statement statement = this.db.getConnection().createStatement();
    int tokens = this.getTokens(p);
    if(tokens!=0){
        statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE 'tokens' SET 'tokens'='"+(tokens+1)+"' WHERE  'username'='"+pname+"'");
    }else{
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO 'tokens' ('username', 'tokens') ('"+pname+"','1');");
    }

}
```

However, adding the Static tag to this public void will cause the this.'s to break as they are not allowed in statics. **How would I run this function from another class, without adding the static?** I apologies if this is a little vague, but if you have any questions please ask.

Comment: Have you made an instance out of that mysql class? Otherwise your method has to be static to refer to it directly (without instance).

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm very new to Java. Here is my complete code to see if I have created an instance: http://pastebin.com/u6PUVh7C

Comment: Hm, looks alright with a quick look. Are you getting any specific errors?

Comment: No, other than when I hover over the _this.mysql.updatePlayer(player);_ It says I need to add a static. I get _Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getVotes(String) from the type MySQLManager_

Comment: Seems to be working on my end. Could you perhaps specify what it is you exactly want? Why does `updatePlayer()` only work when it's static? How do you know it doesn't work when it's normal like it is currently?

Comment: The code uses this. for example _this.getTokens(p);_, and that is disallowed when using static.

I am creating a plugin that on a command ether generates you a entry in a database (if one does not exist), or adds one to your total tokens.

Comment: Well, you can just remove `this.` from in front of those variables/methods. You just have to make sure that every non-local variable (not created inside the method) is also static. You have to use static variables and methods in a static method, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69513/discussion-between-user3576711-and-bono).